# How to fix Type 3 font if I only have access to the pdf file?

Tags: fonts

I am using overleaf. I am uploading a paper for a conference that does not allow Type 3 fonts. I think the issue is in the annotated plots from matplotlib in png. Or something else. However, it is **not** possible for me to re-run the experiments to create the figures again.

Is there a way to force overleaf to not create the Type 3 fonts and to use a non type 3 font? Or is there a way to process the pdf file to change the Type 3 font into another type?

Comment: png files are bitmaps  and don't contain fonts. Check the log-file, most fonts are reported at the end.

Comment: If instead there are figures as pdf files then fonts in those figures could be a problem, the solution there would be to convert those pdf figures into png and then include the pngs in your document.